# Let $K=GF(2)$ and $p(x)= x^3 + x+1.$ Show that $p$ is irreducible in $K[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $K=GF(2)$ and $p(x)= x^3 + x+1$ Show that $p$ is irreducible in $K[x]$

First of all am I right in interpreting:

$$GF(2) = \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z= \{ 0,1\}$$

So basically, $p(x)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $K$, right?

Does that mean if $$p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + .... + a_n x^n$$ and $ p(x) \in K[x]$ means $ K = \{a_0, a_1, a_2,...,a_n\}$, that the coefficients of $p$ are going to come from this tiny set? $\{0,1\}$

Or am I supposed to find the possibilities of $x$ in this set, $\{0,1\}$ because in that case $p(x)$ is irreducible in $K$

Comment: If $p$ is reducible, then it have a root (in this case). But $p(0)=p(1)=1$.

Comment: $K$ is not just a set, but a field. In particular, it is the set $\{0,1\}$ with the rule $1+1=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $P$ was reducible, it would be the product of a polynomial of degree $1$ multiplied by a polynomial of degree $2$. And a polynomial of degree $1$ has a root in the base field.

However your polynomial is never vanishing on $K$.

*Now answering the question in the comment of Siyanda.*

$GF(8)$ is the only finite field with $8$ elements and its dimension over $GF(2)$ is equal to $3$. So $GF(8) \simeq K[X]/(P)$ which means that $P$ has a root in $GF(8)$.

Comment: I think a complete answer should clarify the question, which OP is having a hard time understanding

Comment: I understand that, but the next part of the question says to show that $GF(8)=K[a]$ which I don't think can be done. None of the elements in $GF(8)$ produce a zero in $p$

Comment: @Siyanda Did you mean to say that no element in the field with eight elements is a roof of the polynomial $\;p(x)=x^3+x+1\in K[x]\;$ ? Because if you did you're wrong: not only there is a root for this polynomial in that field, but **all** its roots are there...

Comment: @Timbuc See? I really don't think I get this...

Comment: thank you! I'm not sure I understand but thank you anyway...so I shouldn't go about the business of plugging {0,1,2,...,7} into $p$ like was my plan?

Comment: Take care, the elements of $GF(8)$ are not at all $\{0,1,2,\dots, 7\}$!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net are they $\{0,1,x,x+1,x^2 +x,...\}$?

Comment: @Siyanda Indeed so...but with what rule of multiplication? For me, for example, $\;GF(8)=\Bbb F_2[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle\;$ , and thus *obviously* $\;p(x)\;$ has a root there...but even if instead of the above ideal you choose $\;x^3+x^2+1\;$ , with the rule $\;x^3=x^2+1\;$  say,  we *also* have a root for $\;p(x)\;$ , say $\;x^2+1\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Oven a finite field $\mathbb{K}$, a third-degree polynomial is irreducible **iff** it has no roots in $\mathbb{K}$.

Given that, it is trivial that the only irreducible third-degree polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$ are $x^3+x^2+1$ and $x^3+x+1$.